# Making iFrame loading faster to avoid validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Problem Statement:

I have a .NET user control and I am using an iFrame inside it. I have multiple instances (can be any number) of that control (with an iFrame in it) on a page. I have to load all the controls every time one control state changes. The control has some mandatory fields to fill.

I have a button which navigates to another screen and because each time I load all the controls it takes considerable amount of time for all of them to load. The user is trying to complete all mandatory fields and click the next button, at this instance even though the user completed all mandatory fields, and the control (with iframe) did not load completely, it produces the validation error.

Note: All of the above is in JavaScript, and not server side.

What I tried:

1. I tried showing a modal div till it loads, but I cannot apparently capture the exact load time and the next button can be potentially clicked.
2. I tried having a timeout on the validation functionality, but it works sporadically as the loading is not definitive.
3. I tried having a counter to see how many controls loaded to check the total controls and only then allow the validation functionality to fire, again the in definitive way it loads, does not help.

I know this can be done in a different way but because of the huge effort and time involved, we have to roll with the existing way, and have to fix the issue. Can someone please suggest any pointers/workaround this problem.

Comment: Are the iFrames loading sources from the same domain or different?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. All frames are loading from the same domain, each frame has a set of controls, which is like a form and has mandatory items.

Comment: How did you implement the third option?

Comment: I have a counter defaulted to 0, every time a control is added to the page (because the controls get added dynamically) i increment the counter, I know how many controls i added. So while validating I have to check if all controls loaded is equal to all controls added on screen. If so, then do your validation, validation would pass as everything is alright. I am just trying to delay the validation. Unfortunately i cannot control the load. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Personally, that seems like a good way to go (check the number of iframes, and have a counter of the ones that have been loaded). How does it fail? What error/issues/challenges do you get?

Comment: The array approach does seem to be a good way to go when you control the source of the pages. What do you mean you cannot control the load? If you have access to the pages being loaded, add a function to those pages that calls a parent.frameLoaded function. Should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this one fixed. The fix i believe is a dodge but i did not know any other way.

I took approach 3 as mentioned above. Have a timeout with 1ms and the counter is incremented in that timeout i.e.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   counter++;
}, 1);
```

I have one more counter on my validation code to delay it for 1ms and check the condition if the counter equals all available controls, if not validate again till the condition is false. Otherwise continue.

```
    function validate() {
        if (counter != total number of frames) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                validate();
            }, 1);
            return false;
        }
...
}
```

Thanks all for your inputs, it helped a lot. Hope this will be a last resort solution for similar issues.

Comment: Where do you have that first `setTimeout`?

Comment: sorry for the delay, the timeout is on load of the iframe.